# If $f$ is null outside a compact, then $u(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N}T_y(x)f(y)dy, \ x\in\mathbb{R}^N$ solves $\Delta u = f$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

> Let $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ be a function that aniihilates
>   itself (is null) in the complementar of a compact of $\mathbb{R}^N$. Show that
>   $$u(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N}T_y(x)f(y)dy, \ x\in\mathbb{R}^N$$ is of
>   class $C^{\infty}$ and that $\Delta u = f$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$

In the context of the Representation Theorem, we find a way to represent a function $u$ such that $\Delta u = f$ inside the domain and equal $f$ in the border. I've seen ways on how to arrive at the function that when integrated together with $f$ gives $u$. It was related to functions $\frac{1}{|x-y|^{N-2}}$. These functions don't annihilate outside a compact, but solve the problem.

Thinking a little bit, I must show

$$\Delta u(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\Delta T_y(x) f(y) \ dy = f(x)$$

I know from proofs about the Representation Theorem that if $T$ is such that $\Delta T$ is the dirac delta function, we have the result. But I don't see why it works in this case and this is neither a proof, it must be an analytical proof.

**UPDATE:**

I just noticed it doesn't say anything about what is $T_y$, so I guess it's the green function without the corrector function. Maybe?

**UPDATE:**

$$T_y(x) =- \frac{1}{2\pi}\log |x-y|, \mbox{ for } N= 2\\ \frac{1}{\omega_N}\frac{1}{|x-y|^{N-2}},  \mbox{ for } N\ge 3$$

Comment: do you mean "for $N=2$" at the end

Comment: @mathworker21 yes

Comment: Aren't the $T_y$'s you gave constructed so that $\Delta T_y$ is the dirac delta?

Comment: @mathworker21 yes, they're exactly constructed this way. However I don't think using the dirac delta function is a rigorous proof. I've seen how to arrive at this formula for the representation theorem, but it's not actually the same formula, it just looks a lot like it. Maybe the same reasoning is used. Here's where I found a proof for the representation theorem: https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220b/handouts/greensfcns.pdf

Comment: The dirac delta is rigorous because its rigorous definition is for distributions, which is exactly what we have here. We are integrating against a $C^\infty$ function.

Comment: @mathworker21 I agree but we didn't see distributions yet. I guess the only way my teacher would accept would be for me to prove $\nabla u = f$ analytically without new concepts like distributions or well definitness of the dirac delta function (he hasn't even spoken about it)

Comment: Ok, I understand. But if you don't want to introduce distributions, then you cannot talk about $\Delta T_y$, since $\Delta$ can only be applied to $C^2$ functions as $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}$.

Comment: @mathworker21 I'm confused now. Maybe distributions are the answer then? Or maybe an answer that uses distributions in the low level so it appears just as an analytical proof without any new concepts? Could you sketch how your proof using distributions would look like?

Comment: @mathworker21 could you look at page 6 and 7 of this pdf? https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220b/handouts/laplace.pdf it looks like it proves exactly what I want, does not use distributions explicitly, but doesn't mention $f$ being null outside a compact. It mentions that it has compact support. Is this the same thing?

Comment: @mathworker21 however it proves it's $C^2$ and not $C^{\infty}$

Comment: They use claim 1, which does talk about distributions. Also, to clarify, I was just saying that you need to talk about distributions when talking about $\Delta T_y$ since, by definition, $\Delta T_y$ is a distribution